# Can't add aws-ec2 instance as an authorized redirect URI in google developer's console

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, oauth-2.0, google-api

I added amazonaws.com as an authorized domain, but I still can't add my ec2 instance as the redirect URI. How could this be accomplished?

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 2):

You need to own a domain and then point it to your server (ec2 address above). If you already own the domain, then see the process for pointing the domain to a server in your domain registrar. Then use that url for redirect after auth.

Comment: Thank you. Is there a way to get around this without owning a domain? It's for a school project and I don't think we're expected to own one.

Comment: This maybe too late, but if you still need it you can use http://www.dot.tk/en/index.html?lang=en for a free domain